# Redux-toolKit, обработка ошибок с сервера

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

Друзья всем привет, кто работал с Redux-toolkit требуется помощь.

Я пытаюсь написать свою кастомную функцию которую буду передовать при вызове PayloadCreator в Async Thunk, пример:

```
export const updateCurrentBrand = createAsyncThunk('brand/updateCurrentBrand', protectRequest(brandApi, 'POST'))
```

Тело функции protectRequest:

```
export const protectRequest = (url: string, method: string) => {
    return ({id, data}: any, thunkAPI: any) => {
        fetch(url + (id ? id : ''), {
            method: method,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            signal: thunkAPI.signal,
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(async (response) => {
                console.log(thunkAPI.signal)
                try {
                    const data = await response.json();
                    if (response.status === 200) {
                        return data
                    }
                    if (response.status === 400) {
                        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(data)
                    }
                }
                catch(err) {
                    let error = err
                    if (!error.response) {
                        throw err
                    }
                    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(response)
                }

            })
    }
}
```

В документации есть пример для обратки ошибок уже в компоненте, в моем случае ошибки не попадает и приложение думает что все хорошо, пример проверки в компоненте:

```
formikHelpers.validateForm(newValues)
    .then( async () => {
        const resultAction: any = await dispatch(updateModel({id, data: values}))
        if (updateModel.fulfilled.match(resultAction)) {
            enqueueSnackbar('Модель успешно обновлена', {variant: 'success'})
            dispatch(getBrand())
            goBack()
        } else {
            if (resultAction.payload) {
                const errorMessage: string = resultAction.payload.data.errors.title
                // Being that we passed in ValidationErrors to rejectType in `createAsyncThunk`, those types will be available here.
                formikHelpers.setSubmitting(false)
                enqueueSnackbar(`Ошибка:${errorMessage}, модель была обновлена ранее`, {variant: 'error'})
                goBack()
            }
        }
    })
```

Как в данном случае обработать ошибки с  сервера, заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нашел оптимальное решение данного вопроса

```
export const protectRequest = (url: string, method: string) => {
    return async ({id, data}: {id: string, data: object}, thunkAPI: any) => {
        const response = await fetch(url + (id ? id : ''), {
            method: method,
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        try {
            const payload = await response.json();
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return payload
            }
            if (response.status === 400) {
                return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(payload)
            }
        }
        catch(e) {}
        if(response.status === 401) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(new Error('Ошибка авторизации'))
        }
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(new Error('Ошибка сервера'))
    }
}
```